# laravel 4 passing variables from one view to another on insertion

Tags: variables, view, laravel-4

i need to pass varibles from parent view to child at insertion, something like this on parent view:

```
@yield('content')->(array("foo"=>"bar"))
```

or

```
@yield('content', null, array("foo"=>"bar"))
```

And then in "content" view, something like this:

```
{{ date("m/d/Y", $foo) ))
```

The date is only an example but i need to use the variable, not only text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell from the documentation and the Blade Compiler source code, there's no syntax availble to pass data to a yielded section. The only way seems to be to use `@include`:

```
@include('view', array('foo' => 'bar'))
```

But then you can't use the Blade template inheritance anymore.